# Git extension permissions/rights error during push on private shared server

Tags: git, bash, git-extensions

I am trying to push a project from my local repository to a server of my company to which I have access. I can navigate to the required folder and create a new repository through Git Extensions as shown below (I tried with Git Bash aswell).

[image: Creation of the git Repository]

However, when I try to push to this repository, I get the following error:

```
E:\programs\Git\cmd\git.exe push --recurse-submodules=check --progress
"name_of_remote_repository" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
fatal: 'path_to_initialized_remote_repository'does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read frlom remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Done
```

Screenshot of that error can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FheGM.png).

Before the error, It does tell me that the branches I am trying to push are new, so it can access and read that info somehow, but not push.

Another thing I've tried is to clone my local repository to the remote one once cleared, and it works, all my files are there. But if I try to push to or pull from that same remote repository, I end up with the same error.

What can I do to fix this? How do I make Git Extensions push as me or something like that?

All I can find on the net are GitHub tutorials, which obviously don't apply, and SSH key related questions.

Comment: Please do not include screenshot for error message, but include the message directly in your post using code blocks.

Comment: @blue112 Done. Didn't know this was a best practice as a screenshot is more explicit, since it's neither console nor code.

Comment: If someone is having the same error, and googles it, it will be better if he's able to find your question.